# Git push doesn't reflect the latest push on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have performed git push but it doesn't reflect the recent push to GitLab,
following are the details:

```
**git push -u origin ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV**
Branch 'ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV' set up to track remote branch 'ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date

**git branch**
  ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV
* bug_fixes
  master


**git log**
commit 4a00000000b2000000bfdf1558d5e7420be0a1b1 (HEAD -> bug_fixes)
Author: abc <abc@abc-abc-abc.local>
Date:   Mon Jul 10 13:05:33 2021 +0530

    bug fixes

commit 3700000068377bef5e966213f5fb64c51778349f (origin/ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV, ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV)
Author: def <def.xyz@lmc.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 09 12:53:08 2021 +0530

    abc thing added

**git remote show origin**
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://abc@gitlab.def.com/ABC/Def.git
  Push  URL: http://abc@gitlab.def.com/ABC/Def.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV      tracked
    master                  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV merges with remote ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV
    master                  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV pushes to ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV (up to date)
    master                  pushes to master                  (up to date)


**git remote -v**
origin  http://abc@gitlab.def.com/ABC/Def.git (fetch)
origin  http://abc@gitlab.def.com/ABC/Def.git (push)
```

Could you please help me to get to the issue here?
let me know if you need more logs.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what the problem is. Are you saying that when you look at Gitlab in your web browser, the "ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV" branch does not have the expected commits?

Comment: yes, the latest commit performed using the following command is not available on gitlab: **git push -u origin ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV**.  
Branch 'ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV' set up to track remote branch 'ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date

Comment: So, in the output you show, the commit "3700000068377bef5e966213f5fb64c51778349f" ("abc thing added") is not showing when you look at the branch on Gitlab? Or are you expecting the commit "4a00000000b2000000bfdf1558d5e7420be0a1b1" ("bug fixes") to show up on that branch?

Comment: yes, I am expecting "4a00000000b2000000bfdf1558d5e7420be0a1b1" ("bug fixes") commit to show up in gitlab.

Comment: OK, so there is a misunderstanding somewhere: as shown in your git log output, that commit only exists on the "bug-fixes" branch, not the "ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV" branch.

Comment: Can you clear up your original post? It looks like you have the bug_fix branch checked out as your active local branch. And you are pushing to origin on another branch. I think something like:  ‘git push origin bug_fix:ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV’ would push the changes from your bug_fix branch to the ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV branch.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is not very easy to follow, so let's break down what `git push -u origin ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV` means:

- `git push` updates one or more remote branches based on one or more local branches
- The `-u` option tells git to "set the upstream" for the branch, so that you can use shorter versions of `git push` to do the same thing in future.
- The next argument specifies which remote repository to push to. The name `origin` is just the default name set for the repository you cloned from.
- The last argument specifies both what to push and where to push it; in this case, you've specified just one branch name, which means "push the local branch with this name to the remote branch with the same name".

Note that it doesn't matter which branch you have checked out when you run this command; you have asked git to push the `ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV` branch, which has the tip commit `3700000068377bef5e966213f5fb64c51778349f`. The currently checked out branch, `bug_fixes`, and its tip commit, `4a00000000b2000000bfdf1558d5e7420be0a1b1`, haven't been pushed anywhere.

You probably want to do one of two things:

- Merge the change from `bug_fixes` onto `ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV` and then push it. e.g. `git switch ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV; git merge --ff-only bug_fixes; git push origin ABC_10.0.0.0_DEV`
- Push the `bug_fixes` branch to Gitlab, and then use the Gitlab UI to merge it via a Merge Request. e.g. `git push -u origin bug_fixes`